# How can I validate a filename prior to the SaveFileDialog closing?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I am using a SaveFileDialog and would like to evaluate whether a file meets certain conditions before allowing it to be saved.  If it doesn't meet the criteria, I don't want the SaveFileDialog to close when "Save" is clicked.  I thought the FileOK might work, but the dialog looks like it is already closed by the time that event is fired, and I don't see a way to prevent it from closing in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileOK` is a [`CancelEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventhandler(VS.71).aspx) - you just have to set the [`Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(VS.71).aspx) property of the [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs(VS.71).aspx) to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.  BTW, you have a typo: "CencelEventArgs".

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach from FileOK handler

```
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //your conditions...
    if (!openFileDialog1.FileName.Equals( "C:\\hello.txt" ) )
    {
        //if fail, set e.cancel
        MessageBox.Show(@"File name must equal c:\hello.txt.");
        e.Cancel = true;

    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Controls: The Save File Dialog Box](http://ww.functionx.com/vcsharp2003/controls/savefiledialog.htm)